# Editing Run Configuration for a jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I'm working on a project where i have to expand an existing java application available to me as JAR file.With the exception of a class that adds new modules to the app implementing a certain interface.
I've bin copy/pasting class files inside the jar after compiling them in the command prompt and running the resulting JAR per hand.
Is there a way to create a run configuration in intelliJ that Runs the Jar but with my 1 modified class and some new ones ?

Comment: Explicitly set the class path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the Classpath wasn't the problem. The problem turned out to be JARs inside the JAR file which used some custom loader.
I just needed to extract them and add them as a dependency.
From That point everything worked perfectly.